# Tracking multiple campaigns and products leading to a single Thank you page

Tags: google-analytics

I have multiple campaigns leading to a single landing page offering several different products. Campaigns have unique utm_campaign parameters.

Each product has separate page (url) with some form to fill.

After the form is completed, visitor is going to a Thank you page, which is the same for all products (single url for all of them).

What I want to track is:

- how many people reached Thank you page (I can do that now with that destination url as a goal)
- what products did they purchased (number of goals completed per product)
- which campaign did they come from (number of goals completed per product, per campaign)

I only have access to Google Analytics, there is no Tag manager, and I don't have access to the website code. Everything I can use are utm_campaign parameters, landing page url, separate product pages url's, and single Thank you page url.

Is there any solution to get the requested details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the ideas. I solved this with Advanced segments in GA. To be specific, requested stats are shown this way:

1. New segment
2. Advanced/Sequence
3. Step 1: Campaign + Landing page
4. Immediately followed by Step 2: Thank you page

Answer (score 1):

No. Not that I am aware of.

What you are looking for is Ecommerce Tracking with Google Analytics. Currently you are tracking Campaign data with the use of utm-Parameters. This shows you which Campaigns, Sources, Keywords, etc. are clicked on with that you can cross-reference your campaigns with your Thank-You page.

To track your transactions, purchases, cart values, etc. you need to set up the aforementioned ecommerce tracking... if you do not have access to the source code, maybe you can ask your provider of your shopping cart on how to activate that. For Wordpress/Woocommerce, Magento, Opencart, and all sort of different shopping carts there are plugins which enable ecommerce tracking without you having to edit a single line of code.

Answer (score 1):

It'll be a challenge to get what you're looking without setting up event tracking and ecommerce tracking.

For the third item, since you know the URLs (and the utm campaign codes) you can experiment with "Behavior Flow"; and "referral path" and "previous/next page path" dimensions.

**Using Behavior Flow**
In google Analytics, go to Behavior --> Behavior Flow. It will present you with a user flow diagram of top pages. Change the page by clicking on the cog next to "Landing page" dropdown. In the path, enter a starting point, for example, the first page of a campaign. It'll then show you user path and exits from that point on. Clicking on any of the green boxes will give you options to further fine-tune the graph. I don't know the limit, but in the graph, you can easily add up to 10 steps of interactions.

**Using Dimensions:**
Go to Behavior --> Site Content --> All pages. Here,  you can filter the table by a Primary Dimension and a Secondary Dimension.
For the primary dimension, experiment with using the destination page (the Thank You Page) or an interim page (a campaign page.) Then, filter by secondary dimension.
If your Primary Dim is Thank You page, choose "previous page path" as the secondary dim. If a campaign page is your primary dim., then use "next page path" as secondary dimension.

You can get some meaningful data using these options if all those URLs are unique, and there's some linearity in the user paths.